# Create dynamic calculation with css scale property in javascript for all resoltions

Tags: javascript, css, scale

I have one page website which always should fit in one screen.

The only solution i found for all types of screen resolutions was **css transform:scale** property. So i started to go through all screen resolutions and adding different scale number per resolution but seems to be endless job.

Is there a dynamic calculation way/logic with javascript which will calculate automatically the scale per screen resolution(widthwise/heightwise).

You can find the layout in this [link](http://grandspinfinalversion.ipoint.com.mt/)

What i imagine it to be is

If   900px - 0.87 scale is ok
Then 1440  - X

So X = 1440 * 0.87 / 900

I have some function created but it is not exact

```
function scaleContainer(){
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   var staticNumber = 1.47;
   var calculatedVal = (windowWidth * staticNumber) / 2560  - 0.1;
   var finalVal = calculatedVal.toFixed(2);
   console.log(finalVal);
   $('.main_container').css('transform','scale('+finalVal+')');
}
```

The thing is that the getted number it is near to what i want it to be but not exactly

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: See my updated question @evolutionxbox

Comment: arghhhhhhhhh please stop! Look into media queries or responsive units of measurement such as em, rem, vh etc

Comment: That is an endless job for this type of design @kiwi1342

Comment: Currently am using media queries but i don't want to check every pixel by pixel to be sure that it fits ok. So that's why wanna make it dynamic @kiwi1342

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what media queries are...

Comment: There is nothing to misunderstand just min/max-width, min/max-height, no @evolutionxbox?

Comment: if you want pixel perfect result then you should use responsive units (rem, em, vh.. take a look at those)

Comment: It's not just that no, but I think you're misunderstanding that you don't need to check pixel by pixel. You can use viewport relative units, such as `vw` or `vh`. Media queries are good to check things like orientation or screen ratio.

Comment: @kiwi1342 so it is not possible to create some logic/ratio and automate it?